# Way to identify cause of psycopg2 timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am attempting to connect to a remote postgresql db in Python. I am using `psycopg2`. The following is the format used to establish a connection:

```
con = psycopg2.connect( dbname = config['db'], 
                        host = config['host'], 
                        port = config['port'], 
                        user = config['user'], 
                        password = config['pass'])
```

I have seen noted in other SO questions that `connect_timeout = xx` can be added to specify the timeout delay. Regardless, the issue is that when the timeout does occur it asks if `host` is correct and the `port` is, as well.

They are, and a similar connection set up in Node using `JSFtp` is successful. Are there any additional steps I can take to breaking down the steps `psycopg2` is taking to identify what break is occurring?

Comment: The issue was with AWS' Security Group configuration. I suppose that the fault then lies in my set up, but wondering if, in the future, there would have been a way to identify that issue via the `psycopg2` library. For example, some method of observing that the time out was caused due to some permissions issue. Perhaps this is unreasonable to ask for on the part of `psycopg2`.

Comment: The timeout is occurring because psycopg2 is waiting for a response. That's what a timeout is. If you got an error then the timeout would never happen. All psycopg2 knows is that it is still waiting for a response.